# iOS 7 detail layout when master has navigation bar prompt

Tags: ios, layout, uinavigationbar, master-detail, ios7

I run into a layout problem in iOS 7:

[image: Screenshot]

To reproduce create a simple master-detail-app and insert this line in *MasterViewController.m* :

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"Master";
```

and this in *DetailViewController.m* :

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Both lines in `viewDidLoad`.

The detail view's frame does not update correctly when the navigation bar shrinks to its normal size.

How should I fix this?

Comment: The same problem occurs in the other direction: if the detail has a prompt and the master doesn't, then when the detail view is popped, the master ends up with an ugly black bar below the nav bar.

Comment: Have you tried reporting this as a bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UINavigationItem Prompt Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115821/uinavigationitem-prompt-issue)

Answer (score 3):

My current solution to this is to remove the prompt in the **master view**'s viewWillDisappear:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationItem.prompt = nil;
}
```

Then just set it again in the viewWillAppear.  There should be a better method, however.

Comment: Yeah, that is the same what I did. There must be a better way.

Comment: ...and, this work-around doesn't appear to work when set up the other way (i.e. when it's the detail that has the prompt, and we put this code in the detail's viewWillDisappear).

Comment: @JoeStrout try to nil out the prompt in the master's viewWillAppear