# Navigation bar being pushed up but status bar absence in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, statusbar

When I just return to a viewController from a viewController that has a  prefersStatusBarHidden() = true I get this black stripe under the nav-bar.

After a second the nav-bar realigns itself as per my second image bellow.

Is there a way to avoid that black stripe from happening in Swift?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073865/black-bar-appears-under-navigation-bar

Comment: I did, no success unfortunately.